# php session variable in database

Tags: php, database, session

I'm making a php quiz and in the beginning I ask someone's name. This is stored in a session.
I put the score they get in the variable $score.
At the end, I need to put the name(in the session) and the score they got in a database for the highscore list.
But it just won't work.

Here's my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT into WP12_highscore(name, score) 
       VALUES (" . $_SESSION['name'] . ", $score)");
```

I can't find much about it, but this seems fine to me. It does work when I just put some name and number in, and the $score one works as well(have been experimenting with it so it might be wrong now), but I just can't get the session variable to store in the database..

Comment: You have a quoting problem, the string `$_SESSION['name']` must be enclosed in single quotes in the SQL query. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes and backticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)  Something like `mysqli_query($db, "INSERT into WP12_highscore(name, score) 
 VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['name'] . "', $score)");` noting the addition of the `'` single quotes around the concatenation...

Comment: Now is a great time to start learning [how to use `prepare()/execute()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)for parameterized queries in MySQLi.

Comment: Thank you so much @MichaelBerkowski ! Such a stupid mistake